# How to execute code after concat operator finish

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have tasks (observables) in array and want run them sequentially and at the end I want to run some finish code

```js
const { concat, of, tap } = rxjs;
const { delay  } = rxjs.operators;

let tasks = [
  of(1).pipe(delay(1000)),
  of(2).pipe(delay(2000)),
  of(3).pipe(delay(1000)),
  of(4).pipe(delay(2000)),
];

// In below example, word "Finish" is printed 4 times 
// but I want print it only once, at the end.

concat(...tasks)
  .pipe(tap(()=> console.log('Finish')))      
  .subscribe(n => console.log(`result for task ${n}`));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.0/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-v0/YVjBcbjLN6scjmmJN+h86koeB7JhY4/2YeyA5l+rTdtKLv0VbDBNJ32rxJpsaW1QGMd1Z16lsLOSGI38Rbg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

I try to use `tap` but without success - how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tap, how you use, will run on each emited value.

You should use [finalize](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/finalize) instead.

```js
const { concat, of, finalize } = rxjs;
const { delay  } = rxjs.operators;

let tasks = [
  of(1).pipe(delay(1000)),
  of(2).pipe(delay(2000)),
  of(3).pipe(delay(1000)),
  of(4).pipe(delay(2000)),
];

concat(...tasks)
  .pipe(finalize(()=> console.log('Finish')))      
  .subscribe(n => console.log(`result for task ${n}`));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.0/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-v0/YVjBcbjLN6scjmmJN+h86koeB7JhY4/2YeyA5l+rTdtKLv0VbDBNJ32rxJpsaW1QGMd1Z16lsLOSGI38Rbg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I looking for (I add snippet to your answer) thanks